# SurfaceTexture looses frames

Tags: textures, render, android-mediacodec, surface, decoder

I am decoding frame in Native MediaCodec and sending it to surface.
In Samsung S7 Galaxy(US Version) and Pixel phone, drops the frames sent to surface.
MediaCodec Decoder Decodes at 60fps without any issues.
When I count frames available on the 
void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface) {}, I see only 50-52fps.
I can see the jump in the pts as well associated with surface( Ex: surface.getTimestamp()) 
Any one has idea on this one.

I am able to get it working fine on European version of Samsung Galaxy S7.